# Google app engine Endpoints, Objectify Register

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I start google app engine with endpoints, I use objectify for persistence and I have an little question.(I hope !)

All my apiMethod start like it :

```
@ApiMethod(path = "getAccount", httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET)
public Account getAccount(@Named("idPlayer") long idPlayer) {
    ObjectifyLoader.loadEntity();
```

ObjectifyLoader.loadEntity(); is just a method like it

```
   public static void loadEntity(){
    ObjectifyService.register(Account.class); 
    ObjectifyService.register(WeaponsAccount.class); 
}
```

I got the impression that I register my class et each call to the api.

A tips for load only one time?

Thanks you for reading.
Fabiitch

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a `ServletContextListener`. Check out this [App Engine oage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/getting-started/using-datastore-objectify#the_helper_file_ofyhelperjava) for an example.